# Write in a txt file android java

Tags: java, android, file, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I wish I could get the content that the user enters into a text file, and then read it when the user logs in, yes this is the password. Preferences much use shared or sqlite but I already not happen with a file ... So when I press the button, the content should be written in a text file. Or when I do with the file explorer, nothing .. Thanks for your help! Here is my code:

```
public class MDPinterne extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mdpinterne);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById((R.id.button3));
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText mdp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                String chmdp = mdp.getText().toString();

                try {
                    // open myfilename.txt for writing
                    OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("mdpsecurity",0));
                    // write the contents on mySettings to the file
                    out.write(chmdp);
                    // close the file
                    out.close();
                } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
                    //do something if an IOException occurs.
                }


            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: With nothing in the catch block, we can't know what is wrong. Very bad practice.

Answer (score -1):

Try with this:

```
    File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "YOUR_FOLDER");
    if (!root.exists()) {
        root.mkdirs();
    }
    try
    {
        File mFile;

        mFile = new File(root, "YOUR_FILE_NAME.TXT");

         mFileWriter = new FileWriter(mFile);

        mFileWriter.append("YOUR TEXT");
        mFileWriter.flush();
        mFileWriter.close();

        }
    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And don't forget permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Same nothing happens... Thanks , and I is not external card